# Overload WEB API Token Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Visual Studio provides a nice ready template for ASP.NET WEB API project. There we have a set of account management functions dealing with ASP.NET Identity. However, one most fundamental function is missing both from automatically generated controllers and documentation. Namely, "~/Token" URL, which is used to grant WEB API access tokens is not mentioned anywhere.

I would like to write a custom controller to intercept all "~/Token" calls to make some logging and additional processing in a way similar to other WEB API controllers. How can I do it in a simple and natural way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server. This is the Microsoft extension to add the required functionality. It creates an oauth endpoint (e.g. /token) that you can use to get a token. You don't have a controller directly, but there is a special OWIN class connected to it that you will need to extend to add whatever you need.

You can find more details [here](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) and [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

It's a bit long reading, but it works and I have used it in a few projects.

Here is a simple example how you can do it (`GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` is the most important method for you):

```
    public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            // Add CORS e.g.    
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Provided here are standard ASP.NET Identity links. Sure enough, I have read plenty of them already. But none mentions token entry point overloading. Hence my question. Definitely, OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server is already included into Microsoft template. Question is, is it possible to overload it in an easy way to intercept token creation function or not?

Comment: It depends on what exactly do you want to achieve: add some additional info to the token? (easy), add in your authentication? (easy), change the token format? (don't know)

Comment: I thought on some most easy things, such as adding a log record that a user logged in through WEB API or maybe make some additional verification of user, e.g. through request IP etc. If it can be done with few lines of code, it would be nice. If I must write own Authorization Server to achieve this, it is definitely not worth effort.

Comment: You can do all that you want in your custom implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider. You can find more details in the second link I provided (on Step 10). You can find how to use your provider in Step 9

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly a code snippet I was looking for.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik is there any way to implement token authentication in web api without using owin identity .for example using RNGCryptoserviceprovider to generate  token?

Comment: You can surely roll your own, but I would not recommend that, too time consuming and error prone